# How to export/download Excel View from Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, download, export

Following this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwA7MeuQRik) and this [Git package](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel) I tried implementing a new feature option to export or download excel data from a specific project
but the issue at hand when clicking on the download button nothing happens. any ideas what I did wrong ?

Edit : I already tried changing button type value

[image: Excel Button]

**app\Exports\UsersDataExport**

```
namespace App\Exports;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use App\Models\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

class UsersDataExport implements FromView,ShouldAutoSize
{
    use Exportable;
    private $users;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = User::all();
    }

    public function view() : View
    {
        return view('excel.usersdetails', [
            'users' => $this->users
        ]);
    }
}
```

**app\Http\HomeControllers**

```
use App\Exports\UsersDataExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

public function exportExcel()
{
    return Excel::download(new UsersDataExport, 'users-data.xlsx');
}
```

**routes\web.php**

```
Route::post('users/export-excel', [HomeController::class, 'exportExcel'])->name('users.download-excel')
```

**resources\views\index.blade.php**

```
<div>
 <form action="{{ route('users.download-excel') }}" method="POST" target="__blank">
  @csrf
   <div>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="button">Excel</button>
   </div>
 </form>
  </div>
```

**resources\views\excel\usersdetails.blade.php**

```
<body>
    <table style="position: relative; top: 50px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>nom et prenom du destinaire</th>
                <th>telephone</th>
                <th>code wilaya</th>
                <th>commune de livraison</th>
                <th>adresse de livraison</th>
                <th>montant du colis</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td data-column="nom et prenom du destinaire">John Doe</td>
                <td data-column="telephone">000</td>
                <td data-column="code wilaya">56</td>
                <td data-column="commune de livraison">11</td>
                <td data-column="adresse de livraison">AAA</td>
                <td data-column="montant du colis">100</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think your issue is related to the button but not sure.

Comment: just like @IshakBenaissa said, try to change button type to "submit"

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I already tried that